# How can I programatically initiate "Touch Input Calibration" on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, touch

Is there a way to programatically invoke the touch input calibration on on Windows 10 or newer?
What I am looking for is the **Control Panel** -> **Tablet PC Settings** -> **Display** -> **Display Options** -> **Calibrate...** functionality.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOAdH.png)

Comment: You can open that control panel dialog with this command line "rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL tabletpc.cpl @1" and then use UI Automation to click on the "Calibrate" button https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32